# WebView opening in browser rather than within my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have an adapter that adds data to a layout. One of the elements of the layout is a link. If a user clicks this element, I want it to open the link in a `WebView`.

Right now, I have this code:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    private List<Card> cardData;

    private WebView mWebview;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RelativeLayout link;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            link = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.link);
        }
    }

    public CardAdapter(Context context, List<Card> cardData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cardData = cardData;
    }

    @Override
    public CardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card card = cardData.get(position);

        holder.link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebview  = new WebView(context);

                mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardData.size();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have it set up that if the user clicks the link element, it creates a new `WebView` (and opens `www.google.com`).

My problem is that, right now, it opens the link in a browser rather than opening within my app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code, DONE

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card card = cardData.get(position);

        holder.link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               holder.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

               holder.webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to load in your WebView.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: I get the following error when clicking on the element: `E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver` and `W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 4963`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @user7397971 add this in adapter and try this.

```
imgad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), WebviewActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

and add this activity:WebviewActivity.class

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_webview);
    getIds();
    webview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = this.webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}

private void getIds() {
    try {
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(WebviewActivity.this, "", "Please wait", true);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewurl);
        webview.loadUrl(GlobalField.WEBURL);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                pd.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

 }
```

and add xml this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5_cherish"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/WebViewurl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you have a Webview in the layout. Otherwise this will not bind your webview to your layout, thus opening the url in the browser rather than webview.

Another solution is to open a new Activity which has webview in it as already mentioned above. Pass the URL to the next activity through intent, and OnCreate load the URL you get from the intent